# How to add vertical space after \hline without breaking vertical lines in a table

Tags: tables, rules

I have seen similar questions on the matter ([Question 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196457/add-vertical-space-between-lines-without-breaking-a-vertical-line), [Question 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/130818/how-to-draw-a-double-hline-in-a-table-without-interrupting-vertical-lines)) of adding vertical space and not breaking vertical lines, the solutions suggested are to add space after the `\\` using `\\[0.1cm]` for example or changing the `\arraystretch` which I do not want to do. Using `\\[0.1cm]` allows me to add space just before a `\hline` but not after as well.

How can I add vertical space after a `\hline` without breaking vertical lines in a table?

Please find my MWE below:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \onehalfspacing
  \caption{Table of info.}

    \begin{tabular}{c | c c}
 & C/S Analyser & O/N/H Analyser \\
 & EMIA 320 V2 & EMGA 830 \\[0.1cm]
   \hline
   \noalign{\vskip 0.1cm}
Sensitivity (ppm) & 0.1 & 0.001 \\
Furnace type & Induction & Impulse \\
Carrier gas & Pure O2 & Pure He \\[0.1cm]
   \hline
    \end{tabular}

  \doublespacing
  \label{tab:chem}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Look in ``booktab`` packages. It offer ``\toprule``, ``\midrule``, ``\bottomrule``, ..., ``\addlinespace``. It is dedicated to write beautiful tables.

Comment: Instead of a `\vskip`, place a large(r) vertical strut inside the first cell; something like `\rule{0pt}{\dimexpr.7\normalbaselineskip+1mm}`. For more on table-related struts, see [Column and row padding in tables](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31704/5764).

Comment: @Werner thanks for your suggestion, I will have a read, anything I can learn is more than welcome

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do that with the `cellspace` package: define a minimal vertical padding of rows, and prefix the relevant column specifier with the letter `S` (or `C` if you use `siunitx`):

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx}
\doublespacing
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{5pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \onehalfspacing
  \caption{Table of info.}
  \begin{tabular}{c | Sc c}
    \hline
                      & C/S Analyser & O/N/H Analyser \\
                      & EMIA 320 V2 & EMGA 830 \\
    \hline
    Sensitivity (ppm) & 0.1 & 0.001 \\
    Furnace type & Induction & Impulse \\
    Carrier gas & Pure O2 & Pure He \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}

  \doublespacing
  \label{tab:chem}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will make use of this method in future tables though for this one I will use the above answer by Arash, I accept your response as it answers my question however for anyone else who in future may need to adopt this method

Comment: I agree the solution without vertical lines is much more beautiful (and that's what I do usually). Let me say that booktabs adds some vertical padding to horizontal rules, which you can customise changing the values of `aboverulesep` and `\belowrulesep`. But `cellspace` is a quite useful package in many cases, as vertical spacing in latex's tables is often much too tight.

Comment: Thank you for your addition of info, I am still learning the tricks of the dark art of table making and I do try to generally avoid vertical lines if not necessary as it does make a table much more pleasant.

Answer (score 7):

Add `\\\\[-1.5\medskipamount]` after `\hline`
This will make one more row with small height.

The value before medskipamout should be chosen appropriately.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you drop the vertical line completely.  How about something like this?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{array,tabularx,booktabs}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
  \centering
  \onehalfspacing
  \caption{Table of info.}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}ccc@{}}
      \toprule
      Parameter & C/S Analyser & O/N/H Analyser \\
                & EMIA 320 V2 & EMGA 830 \\%
      \cmidrule(r){1-1}\cmidrule(lr){2-2}\cmidrule(l){3-3}
      Sensitivity (ppm) & 0.1 & 0.001 \\
      Furnace type & Induction & Impulse \\
      Carrier gas & Pure O2 & Pure He \\[0.1cm]
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
  \doublespacing
  \label{tab:chem}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response, I quite like your method of dealing with the issue for this particular table, I am not sure I quite understand the use of the `@{}` symbol when defining the table, is there an easy explenation to that notation?

Comment: I will accept the below answer by Bernard as it answers my question but I will be using your solution as it is stylistically superior to my original table in many ways.

Comment: `@{}` kills the horizontal space included by LaTeX at the beginning or end of a cell.  Take a closer look at the position of **S**ensitivity and O/N/H Analyse**r**.

Comment: Ooooh I see, cause it wasn't really explained in great detail within the tabular and tabularx package instructions and had left me rather confused. Thank you, that clears much of my confusion to some notation. Have a good day!

Comment: This is a feature of vanilla LaTeX, no extra package needed.  E.g., try `texdoc lshort`, section `2.11.6 Tabular`.

Answer (score 3):

In case, that you not need `array` and`colortbl` in other tables, than you can obtain beautiful table by means of (almost forgotten) package `mdwtab`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
    \usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mdwtab,tabularx}
\doublespacing

\usepackage[active,floats,tightpage]{preview}
    \setlength\PreviewBorder{1em}

    \begin{document}

    \onehalfspacing
\begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\caption{Table of info.}
    \label{tab:chem}
        \begin{tabular}{c | c c}
    \hlx{hv}
    & C/S Analyser & O/N/H Analyser \\
    & EMIA 320 V2 & EMGA 830 \\
    \hlx{vhv}
Sensitivity (ppm) & 0.1 & 0.001 \\
Furnace type & Induction & Impulse \\
Carrier gas & Pure O2 & Pure He \\
    \hlx{vh}
        \end{tabular}

\end{table}
    \doublespacing
    \end{document}
```

If you need more vertical space around midle line in table, just add additional `v` in `\hlx` parameters. for example `\hlx{vvhvv}`. For more information about this package read manual (it is in dvi format).

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sharing this more "underrated" package I will experiment with it at a future date, do you know why it's almost forgotten? Are you sure it's not simply outclassed by more recent ones? Just curiosity questions :)

Comment: This package is to my opinion very powerful. Its week point is that it is not compatible with ``array``, ``... [table]xcolor`` and/or ``\colortbl``. Probably that is reason why it is not wide used (conclusion I made on facts, that recent ten years I didn't observe any mention of it). Another reason can be that Mark Wooding, author of package, around 2002 left his activity in (La)Tex "domain" and stop with maintaining/improving his packages. I still regularly use ``mdwab``, especial in cases of writing tables with transformation pairs (like Fourier, etc) than when I use footnotes in table etc.

Comment: Thank you for your explenation, I will experiment in future tables then as I do not foresee requiring colour for the time being, much appreciated for your help, have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, the vertical rules are never broken, even by `\noalign{\vskip ...}` (because they are, in fact, drawn by PGF/Tikz after the construction of the array).

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[left=2.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\doublespacing

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\onehalfspacing
\caption{Table of info.}
\begin{NiceTabular}{c|cc}
& C/S Analyser & O/N/H Analyser \\
& EMIA 320 V2 & EMGA 830 \\[0.1cm]
\hline
\noalign{\vskip 0.1cm}
Sensitivity (ppm) & 0.1 & 0.001 \\
Furnace type & Induction & Impulse \\
Carrier gas & Pure O2 & Pure He \\[0.1cm]
\hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\doublespacing
\label{tab:chem}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

However, I recommend to do tabulars with `booktabs` (and in the spirit of `booktabs`).

Answer (score 0):

An easy solution with `tblr` environment of [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package: you can use `abovesep+` option inside `\SetRow` command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{c|cc}
\hline
 Alpha   & Beta  & Gamma   \\
\hline
 Epsilon & Zeta  & Eta     \\
\hline
\SetRow{abovesep+=4pt}
 Iota    & Kappa & Lambda  \\
\hline
 Nu      & Xi    & Omicron \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]